# Maintain order of jq CSV output and include empty values

Tags: json, csv, tags, jq, aws-cli

I am currently working on a bash script that combines the output of both the `aws iam list-users` and `aws iam list-user-tags` commands in a CSV file containing all users along with their respective information and assigned tags. To parse the JSON output of those commands I choose to use `jq`.

Retrieving parsing and converting (JSON to CSV) the `list-user` output works fine and produces the expected comma-separated list of values.

The output of `list-user-tags` does not quite behave that way. Its JSON output has the following schema:

```
{
    Tags: [
        {
            Key: "Name",
            Value: "NameOfUser"
        },
        {
            Key: "Email",
            Value: "EmailOfUser"
        },
        {
            Key: "Company",
            Value: "CompanyOfUser"
        }
    ]

}
```

Unfortunately the order of the tags is not consistent across users (and possibly across queries) which currently makes it impossible for me to maintain the order defined in the CSV file. On top of that there is the possibility of one or multiple missing tags.

What I am looking for is a way to achieve the following (preferably using `jq`):

1. Select a tags "Value"-value by its "Key"-value
2. Check whether it is existent and if not add an empty entry
3. Put the value in the exact same place every time (maintain a certain order)
4. Repeat for every entry in the original output
5. Convert the resulting array of values into CSV

What I tried so far:

```
aws iam list-user-tags --user-name abcdef --no-cli-pager \
| jq -r '[.Tags[] | select(.Key=="Name"),select(.Key=="Email"),select(.Key=="Company") | .Value // ""] | @csv'
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose your sample "schema" is in a file named schema.jq

Then

```
jq -n -f schema.jq | jq -r '
  def get($key):
    map(select(.Key == $key))
   | if length == 0 then null else .[0].Value end;

   .Tags | [get("Name"), get("Email"), get("Company")] | @csv
'
```

produces the following CSV:

```
"NameOfUser","EmailOfUser","CompanyOfUser"
```

It should be easy to adapt this illustration to your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! Though I am not sure I fully understand your solution. What is the first part used for? Actually there is no fixed schema - as stated tags could be missing and out of order. How is that handled in your solution?

Comment: The "out of order" bit is taken care of by the ordering of the `get` statements. I thought you already had a handle on handling missing objects, but I've elaborated the program to give an illustration of how that can be done.  As I said, it should be quite easy for you to adapt the solution to your specific needs, which are not too clear by the way.  Have you read the guidelines at [mcve]?

Comment: My question includes the five steps I want achieve - one of which is "Check whether it [the value] is existent and if not add an empty entry". Further above it says "On top of that there is the possibility of one or multiple missing tags.".

Do you want me to add another JSON example with one tag missing?

Comment: You really ought to learn some jq. I think the answer covers the cases you mention, but as I indicated, it would be a good idea to provide a sample JSON (not the schema) that covers all your corner cases.